# Collatz Conjecture proof that no cycle can exist other than the 1,4,2 cycle. Can someone verify it?

Tags: proof-verification, collatz-conjecture

This is not a proof of the Collatz Conjecture, but I somehow managed to show that there is no cycle that can exist other that the 1, 4, 2 cycle:

$n$ is a positive integer

$3n+1$, $n$ is odd

$\frac n2$, $n$ is even

First, let us assume that a cycle that does not contain 1 exists. This cycle must contain an odd number within it, otherwise it would be possible to continously divide each number in the cycle by 2, which would lead to 1. Thus, let us begin this cycle with that odd number and because this is a cycle, it does not matter where we begin. Let that odd number be $A$, where $A$ is not equal to 1. Since $A$ is odd, we apply the odd equation to find the next term: $3A+1=B$. $B$ must be an even number since, $3A$ will produce an odd number and adding $1$ to an odd number must give an even number. To find the next term we apply the even formula to $B$: $\frac B2=C$.

Now becuase the domain of $n$ is defined to be the positive integers, $n<3n+1$ must be true for all $n$, thus $A<B$. By the same logic $3n+1>\frac{3n+1}{2}$             thus $B>C$. Now $n<\frac{3n+1}{2}$ only when $n>-1$, so becuase the domain of $n$ is all positive integers we can say that $A<C$. Thus we can form the inequality $A<C<B$.

Since this is a cycle, the values within it must return to $A$ at some point. Let us denote the value right before $A$ by the letter $Z$. Since $A$ is an odd number, $Z$ must be even because the only equation that can return an odd number is $\frac n2$. Becuase $\frac Z2=A$, $Z<A$ must be true. Because $Z<A<C$ is true, $Z<C$ must also be true.

Becuase $\frac Z2=A$, we can say that $Z=2A$. We also know that $3A+1=B$ so $A= \frac{B-1}{3}$. Substituting for $A$ we get $Z=2(\frac{B-1}{3})$. Again, we also know that $\frac B2=C$ so $B=2C$. Substituting in for $B$ we get $Z=2(\frac{2C-1}{3})$ or $Z=\frac{4C-2}{3}$.

Because we know $Z<C$, we can say $\frac{4C-2}{3}<C$ which is only true when $C<2$. The only positive integer less than 2 is 1, so $C=1$. Because $\frac B2=C$, $B=2$. Also because $3A+1=B$, $A=\frac 13$. The domain of $n$ is all positive integers, thus this is a contradiction. Therefore, there exists no cycle that does not contain the number 1 given the parameters set by the conjecture.

Comment: Finding the mistake(s) in your work is your job, not ours.

Comment: I found no mistakes, so I wanted to verify it.

Comment: Because $Z/2=A$, $Z<A$ must be true appears to be the first mistake.

Comment: When you find no mistakes, it's time to look more carefully.

Comment: I see. It is the other way around, $A<Z$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Finding mistakes in people's work should always be a job we partake in...if you don't, your're placing faith in "authority", which is illogical.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If you don't want to answer the question then ignore it.  Every question on here is in some form or other, a request to find some truth which the asker can't find themselves.

Comment: I believe that all question are welcome in this site, but we have in a hand your mistakes, or my mistakes in myself posts, and in the other hand the opinion of users with a lot experience. The experience must prevail, it is the athorithy. Some days I am editing bad posts in this site that after I delete, but in every my posts and comments I try that the people interested in my question, knows/have the best impression of my attitude, I say from my words **thanks in advance, sorry for my diffuse question, please...** I say this since I believe that can help to you. Welcome to MSE and good luck.

Comment: One thing that might help find errors is to note that the if you replace $3n+1$ with $3n+5$, there *are* cycles containing odd number other than $1$ - among others, there's a cycle containing the odd numbers $23,\,37$ and $29$. A good exercise is to trace through your logic and see where it falls apart in this case. This is more effective than just rereading the proof since now you know that you *have* to find somewhere the proof breaks down, since otherwise it's proving something false. Here, you'd probably find the line $Z<A$ and realize it's false in both $3n+1$ and $3n+5$ cases.

Comment: @Zach, I don't know what yoou mean by saying "you're placing faith in authority". I'm certainly not placing faith in the authority of B Sandoval.

Comment: @Robert, not every question here is a claim to have solved a notorious open problem using a couple of paragraphs of high school algebra. I don't want to answer the question, I want to encourage the asker to answer it him- or her-self.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "Finding the mistake(s) in your work is your job, not ours"...so you say finding mistake(s) in someone else's work is the author's job, not yours. This implies that a reader shouldn't be looking for mistakes. That's the author's job. There are two alternatives then, either the reader is skeptical, thinks there are mistakes, and decides to not look for them, or the reader trusts that the author found all the mistakes. Assuming, the reader isn't obstinant, the reader has to trust the author, an authority for the work. That's an appeal to authority, which is illogical...

Comment: @Zach, I don't have to find the mistakes in Sandoval's work, I just have to know that they are there. That's not being obstinate, that's being sensible.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So your assuming there are mistakes, but refuse to actually point them out...I'm done discussing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Mathematics Stack Exchange is for students *of all levels*. Don't discourage ambition.

Comment: @Robert, I am encouraging students, if they are ambitious to do what mathematicians do, to do what mathematicians do, which is to be their own severest critics.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I came to Mathematics Stack Exchange exactly because I knew the proof had to be incorrect somewhere, but I could not find where, perhaps I didn't make that clear. I appreciate those who pointed out the mistake  I glossed over while checking again and again and for providing me with more information on the problem, thank you for helping me out rather than complaining that I came here to ask for help with something I couldn't find.

Comment: "I knew the proof had to be incorrect somewhere, but I could not find where, perhaps I didn't make that clear." Perhaps? Perhaps??? What you wrote was, "I somehow managed to show that there is no cycle that can exist other that the 1, 4, 2 cycle." No indication whatsoever that you "knew the proof had to be incorrect somewhere," --- quite the contrary.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry I didn't make that clear. I didn't think it was relevant to my actual question. There was no way I expected to have solved a problem that has plagued mathematicians for decades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Because $\frac{Z}{2}=A \Rightarrow Z \lt A$"

Is not true. However,

$$\frac{Z}{2}=A \Rightarrow Z \gt A$$

If $Z \lt C$ then your argument is unaffected.

If $Z \gt C$ then your argument is affected. Specifically,

$$\cfrac{4C-2}{3} \not \lt C$$

But rather,

$$C \lt \cfrac{4C-2}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow C \gt 2$$

Answer (score 2):

"Because $\frac{Z}{2}=A, Z<A$ must be true. "

Your contradiction is a consequence of this inequality, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A further, and more fundamental oversight which you may want to look at is that I think your proof doesn't cater for repeated sequences of dividing by two in-between each $3x+1$.  A powerful way to attack the existence of nontrivial loops in the Collatz conjecture is to start with the *minimal* odd number in some cycle and then to attempt to prove that it is 1, or that if it's not 1 then there is necessarily some lower odd number in the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You assume $C=B/2$ and then argue for relation of $A$ and $C$ only. But this means, you are only looking for a 1-odd-step cycle (other than the trivial one). But in half of the cases $C=B/4$ or $C=B/8$ and so on. Moreover, even if $C=B/2$ and $C$ is odd, then further steps with $D,E,F,G,...$ might follow, in which the trajectory goes back near to or below $A$. So not much, if anything at all, has been proved there...

---

The proof for the (odd) 1-step-cycle (which I understood you have attempted, hope I didn't misunderstood you) is easy:
$$ A= {3A+1 \over 2^a} \qquad \quad \text{with } a\ge 1 \text{ such that the rhs is odd}$$
Then
$$ 2^a = {3A+1\over A}  \implies 2^a = 3+\frac1A
$$
and the only possible positive integer on the rhs is $4$ which is also $4=2^2$ so $a=2$ follows; with this we have the solution $A=1$ and no other solution (for $A \ge 1$) is possible.